# Gradle 7.x cannot find matching groovy-all:4.0.1 version

Tags: gradle, groovy

I wanted to include `groovy-all` dependency:

```
testImplementation "org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1"
```

But it seems that https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/groovy/groovy-all/4.0.1/groovy-all-4.0.1.module
does not declare needed attributes:

```
No matching variant of org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 17, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.3.3' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a platform and the consumer needed a runtime of a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'enforcedApiElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all-derived-enforced-platform:4.0.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of an enforced platform and the consumer needed a runtime of a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'enforcedRuntimeElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all-derived-enforced-platform:4.0.1 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an enforced platform and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'groovydocElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1 declares a runtime of a component:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a platform and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
```

Is it something with a groovy publishing process, or did I make something wrong?

Comment: "I wanted to include groovy-all dependency:" - The code you show is for `groovy`, not `groovy-all`.  Those are 2 separate artifacts.  Are you trying to pull in `groovy-all`, `groovy`, or both?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I tried to pull `groovy-all`, edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `-all` dependency is something like a `pom` so I needed to use `platform`:

```kotlin
testImplementation platform("org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.1")
```